# AngularJS : Scope inaccessible in directive after minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify, angular-directive

Accessing scope in a link function within a directive is "undefined" following minification for a number of examples (using Closure Compiler) but works fine pre-minification.

For example, code below from the Angular tutorial with some alterations. After minification $scope.format is not picked up by the directive at any point. The directive shows the default format (Jul 15, 2015) without any errors. Prior to minification, the directive displays format as defined in $scope.format (7/15/2015 12:09:04 AM).

app.js

```
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.format = 'M/d/yy h:mm:ss a';
}])
.directive('myCurrentTime', bd.myCurrentTime.Directive.factory)
```

myCurrentTime-directive.js

```
'use strict';

goog.provide('bd.myCurrentTime.Directive.factory');

/**
 * Example directive factory.
 * 
 * @return {Object}
 * @ngInject
 * @export
 */
bd.myCurrentTime.Directive.factory = function ($interval, dateFilter) {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var format,
        timeoutId;

        function updateTime() {
            element.text(dateFilter(new Date(), format));
        }

        scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function (value) {
            format = value;
            updateTime();
        });

        element.on('$destroy', function () {
            $interval.cancel(timeoutId);
        });

        // start the UI update process; save the timeoutId for canceling
        timeoutId = $interval(function () {
            updateTime(); // update DOM
        }, 1000);
    }

    return {
        link: link
    };
};
// Added by ng-annotate
bd.myCurrentTime.Directive.factory.$inject = ["$interval", "dateFilter"];
```

html file:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
    Date format: <input ng-model="format"> <hr />
    Current time is: <span my-current-time="format"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide plunkr for minified and nonminified variant?

Comment: What library do you use for minification?

Comment: @tomepejo First sentence, he's using Google's Closure compiler.

Comment: @Agop, methinks in advanced mode, Google's Closure compiler can not minify `$scope.format` to `$scope.f` but delete it because it not used in function

Comment: @Grundy Yeah, that might be possible too. That's why we need to see the minified code. Either way, using the string export *should* help, based on what we have to work with so far.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I'm using advanced mode. Answer below part 2 is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the Closure compiler's Advanced Compilation mode? Without seeing your minified code it's hard to pinpoint the problem, but here are some ideas:

1. In this part of your code:

   ```
   .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
     $scope.format = 'M/d/yy h:mm:ss a';
   }])
   ```

   `$scope.format` might be renamed to something like `s.f`. Normally, this wouldn't be a problem, especially since `$scope` is injected properly. However, you're referencing the `format` property in the HTML, which the Closure compiler doesn't know about:

   ```
   Date format: <input ng-model="format"> <hr />
   Current time is: <span my-current-time="format"></span>
   ```

   Try using `$scope['format'] = 'M/d/yy h:mm:ss a'` instead - the Closure compiler never changes strings, so this should export the correct property name for the HTML. Now, remember - [once you use a string to access a property, *always* use a string to access that property](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations#implications-of-global-variable-function-and-property-renaming).
2. Similar to #1, `attrs.myCurrentTime` might be renamed to something like `a.m`. Try using a string property name (`attrs['myCurrentTime']`) to ensure that the compiled JavaScript matches the HTML properly.

Again, these are just ideas at this point. If you post the minified code as a full example, we'll be able to help more.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. That makes far more sense now. Idea 1 does not make a difference (as the minified code still has x.format in it). However, idea 2 fixed the issue and also fixed the issue in the more complicated application I'm writing. Cheers!